# PHP adduser to ubuntu not setting right home directory?

Tags: php, ubuntu

i have this PHP code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);



if(!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['mem']) && !empty($_GET['id']) &&!empty($_GET['k'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $mem = $_GET['mem'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $pass = $_GET['k'];
    $name =  $user."-".$id;
    $directory = "/home/servers/".$name;
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

    echo "User: ".$user; 
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Memory: ".$mem;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "ID: ".$id; 
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Pass: ".$pass;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Directory: ".$directory;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "name: ".$name;
    echo "<br/>";

    if (!file_exists($directory)) {
        mkdir($directory, 0, true);
    }
    else {
        echo "Dir already exists?";
    }
    $outputuser = shell_exec("sudo useradd -s /bin/false -d ".escapeshellarg($directory)." -p ".crypt($pass,$salt)." ".escapeshellarg($servername));

}


?>
```

now when i run the page i get this output

```
User: trotski94
Memory: 1024
ID: 1
Pass: test
Directory: /home/servers/trotski94-1

name: trotski94-1
Dir already exists?
```

which is expected. but when i go to login on the ubuntu machine it says there is no home directory, using / as home instead, why is the -d flag not setting the home directory?

Comment: How are you entering a password for `sudo`? And is whatever user the script is running under in sudoers? Try `system()` instead of `exec()` so you can get the system response.

Comment: www-data group does not need a password for useradd in the sudoers file. the user is created it has nothing to do with the validity of whether it can create a user for not. i can log in as said user he just has no home directory, when i do cat /etc/passwd i see `trotski94-1:x:1001:1001::/home/servers/trotski94-1:/bin/false`

Answer (score 0):

check user directory by:
     cat /etc/passwd | grep trotski94

mayby escapeshellarg may spoil something

Comment: that just returns `trotski94-1:x:1001:1001::/home/servers/trotski94-1:/bin/false` i dont see the problem :S

Comment: whether the user has permissions to the directory? (must have X access)